# Kubernetes service account does not have assigned role?

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift, rbac

I have a service account in kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: testsa
  namespace: project-1
```

And I've assigned it the `view` role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: testsa-view
  namespace: project-1
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: testsa
  namespace: project-1
```

This should grant the service account read access to all resources. Inside a pod in the `project-1` namespace I am trying to run the following Python code:

```
>>> from kubernetes import client, config
>>> config.load_incluster_config()
>>> api = client.CoreV1Api()
>>> api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
```

But this fails with a `403` error:

```
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
[...]
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:project-1:testsa\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

The pod is associated with the service account:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: testsa
  name: testsa-2-l929g
  namespace: project-1
spec:
  serviceAccountName: testsa
  automountServiceAccountToken: true
  containers:
  - image: larsks/testsa
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: testsa
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
```

And inside the container, I can see the mounted secrets:

```
/src $ find /run/secrets/ -type f
/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_09_04_16_30_26.292719465/ca.crt
/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_09_04_16_30_26.292719465/token
/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_09_04_16_30_26.292719465/service-ca.crt
/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_09_04_16_30_26.292719465/namespace
/run/secrets/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
/run/secrets/rhsm/ca/redhat-entitlement-authority.pem
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says `cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope` because you are trying to access all pods of all namespaces across the cluster instead of all pods of only `project-1` namespace.

So change the `Role` to a `ClusterRoleBinding`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: testsa-view
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: testsa
  namespace: project-1
```

Referring from the examples [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-rolebinding) `RoleBinding` always gives permission to namespace scoped resources limited to only that specific namespace even if you are referring to a `ClusterRole` in it.

You can use below commands to check permission of a service account

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:project-1:testsa
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:project-1:testsa -n project-1
kubectl auth list pods --as=system:serviceaccount:project-1:testsa
kubectl auth list pods --as=system:serviceaccount:project-1:testsa -n project-1
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I should have spotted that myself, and I see that if I just call `api.list_namespaced_pod("project-1')` it works fine.